# How to sandbox IPC?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ipc

I have a program that automatically closes if there is another instance running. The only way to run multiple instances is to use Sandboxie.

In Sandboxie, I grant the program full access to every file, the Registry, etc and it still runs. But as soon as I let it have access to IPC without any restriction, it refuses to run multiple instances.

Also, the program automatically closes if Process Explorer (a tool from Microsoft) is running, even sandboxed.

I guess the program accesses the list of running process, and if a specific process is running, like itself or Process Explorer, it terminates.

Any idea how I can prevent this program from accessing process list/IPC without using Sandboxie?

Maybe some custom `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`, or a hook on some functions?

Comment: What about running the program in virtual machines instead of a sandbox? Use a separate VM for each program instance. Processes can't see each other across VM boundaries (unless they communicate with each other via networking)

Comment: It's a really heavy solution, I want something as light as possible

Comment: Patch `NtQuerySystemInformation (NTDLL)` and filter for `SystemProcessInformation` class, then after call is done and if it was successful, modify the data being handed back to the caller-supplied buffer to take care of the process enumeration situation.

Comment: For the IPC, you need to discover what IPC technique it is relying on before you can subvert it. Sandboxie relies pretty much on subverting. Its not really "virtual" like some other sandboxes or a VM, it mainly just uses a kernel-mode driver to filter and edit data for operations (via kernel-mode callbacks) combined with user-mode API hooking.

Comment: IMO, find another way if this is for consumer usage by others. But if it is just an experimental/yourself, then should be fine.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR just for myself and to learn new things, for consumer usage buying a sandboxie licence would be the best.

Comment: _For the IPC, you need to discover what IPC technique it is relying on before you can subvert it_ The problem is that the program won't run if ProcessExplorer is running, do you know what software I could use to identify the exact IPC technique?

Comment: Reverse engineer the program and you'll find out the IPC technique. You won't necessarily need to perform dynamic analysis to find out - depending on the program, could be as simple as checking static imports.

Comment: I don't really know how to reverse engineer a program, but I found that process started with a low integrity can't access to `NtQuerySystemInformation` and it seems to be used in sandbox software. I found a code to start a process as low integrity on Microsoft website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx) but I have an error about the `TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL` type that isn't declared (I should maybe create a new question).

Comment: You can find `_TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_token_mandatory_label - should be defined in `winnt.h` according to MSDN docs.

Comment: _You can find _TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL here: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/… - should be defined in winnt.h according to MSDN docs_ got windows.h and winnt.h included, but it doesn't compile :-/ there are errors in there code, `pIntegritySid` is declared twice, `TokenIntegrityLevel` isn't declared at all.

Comment: Try ProcessMonitor. Even if it won't start, you will see some activity that could give you some clues.

Comment: @DanielSęk I already tried, lot of file and registry access, but I know it's not file/registry related, I gave it full access to both under sandboxie and I can still run multiple instance. There are thousands of operation appearing ProcessMonitor, but I don't see anything related to IPC (Not sure what I should look for actually).